# Extra Tabs automatically added to webpage

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have a codeigniter application.

I am not sure what is going wrong! I have extra tabs added to the start of the output.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

In the above HTML output, before the **`<!DOCTYPE html>`** there are extra spaces added to the output.

any suggestions what could possible cause this. I have not modified the output class at all.

Please suggest!

This is causing a lot of problems when i generate an XML document, specially wsdl XML for creating a soap server.

Comment: shouldn't `<html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->` have to be `<html lang="en" class="ie8"> <!--[endif]-->`

Answer (score 2):

The solution might be in [this thread](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/136008/#670741).
Are you closing your php tags ?

It's actually a CI [FAQ](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/FAQ) (Search "whitespace").

Comment: Thanks @Jerska, however, i am not closing any php tags!

Comment: Well then, maybe before, like empty lines with trailing whitespaces, something like that ? Or some echo's of spaces ?

Comment: Have you got any leading whitespace before the `<?php` in your controller?

Comment: @Malachi there is no whitespace before the <?php tag!